# How to make Windows 10 running faster in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, memory

Installed Windows 10 in VirtualBox with high spec PC. Even I set the memory to 8GB to run the virtual OS, when I operate it felt very slow.

I saw its `Video Memory` in `Display` setting is only 128 MB. Can it be changed? Or is there a way to let it run faster?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start up your VM and on the VM window, go to Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image. Find the image in your VM and install and restart the VM. This should make the VM feel visually smoother.

Comment: this is the most common issue when many people installs a new VM. The "Guess Additions" is actually drivers for graphics, network and many other devices as well as many useful tools like drag and drop, free resolution resizing. Without it the VM is very impractical to use

Comment: Actually I already did it and restarted the OS. But still the same slow experience.